# Notation ::after css, not work in directive of Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, directive, angular-directive

I need is an asterisk in the required fields
I have this code

```
.required label::after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
}
```

in my html

```
<div class="required" >
  <label for="entity"> entity </label>
  <div>
    <select id="entity">
      <option value="">Entity</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works well.

but I want to put it in a directive.

this is my directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[lambRequired]',
  host: {
    '[style.after.content]': '"*"',
    '[style.after.color]': '"red"',
  },
})
export class RequiredDirective {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

and in my html

```
  <div >
    <label lambRequired for="entity"> entity </label>
    <div>
      <select id="entity">
        <option value="">Entity</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but this does not work anymore

help me I will be grateful.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this by using this approach since pseudo elements are not actually part of the DOM tree. As a consequence of that they are not exposed in any manner on the DOM API.

For you to be able to work with pseudo elements you would need to use a class / css like you were doing before.

But unless you were planning to have more functionality on the directive don’t see what kind of gain you would have to create a directive that would just change the color of the text and append an asterisk without any actual logic or event monitoring. A css class would be way more efficient for such a simple goal.